# mod_rewrite seo friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I make youtube lets play videos and am in the process of making myself a website however i am getting stuck at making some SEO friendly urls with mod_rewrite below is the code that i am using

```
RewriteRule /lets-play/(.*)/games.php /lets-play.php?platform=$1
```

The above just doesn't work, get a 404 when visiting the expected page of lets-play/PS4/games.php
also tried

```
RewriteRule /lets-play-(.*)-games.php /lets-play.php?platform=$1 (this is the ideal solution)
RewriteRule /lets-play/(.*)\games.php /lets-play.php?platform=$1 (results in 500 error)
```

What i have at the moment is a page where you can pick a platform from an available list (ps4, xbox one, pc, etc) once you pick one you will be taken to a url that has ?platform=PS4 (or what ever you picked) however what im wanting to have is lets-play-ps4-games if possible if not lets-play/ps4/games will do

Is there anything obviously wrong with my code that i'm missing? i'm assuming that the rewrite just masks the url to make it appear as something else also rewrite engine is on.

Cant provide link as its on localhost.

Thanks,

James.

Edit

I should add I'm a complete novice at htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first slash from your `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule lets-play-(.*)-games.php lets-play.php?platform=$1 [L,QSA] # your ideal solution
RewriteRule lets-play/(.*)/games.php lets-play.php?platform=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also add `[L]` to stop looking for matches after finding this one

and `QSA` to append query strings properly..

That means

`lets-play/PS4/games.php?date=today` 
will rewrite properly to

`lets-play.php?platform=PS4&date=today`

Comment: Thanks for the help im now getting an error saying "The requested URL /lets-play.php was not found on this server." not 100% sure as i 100% have a page called that.

Comment: Well the rewrite is working now then.. take the `/` out of `/lets-play.php`.. i bet this is because you're in a site like... `localhost/test/lets-play-ps4-games.php` and its looking for `/localhost/lets-play.php` not `/localhost/test/lets-play.php`

Comment: @jphillip724 i have updated my answer with the removed slashes

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks so much damn its ALWAYS the small stuff was just a / lol, when i can i'll mark this as the right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @jphillip724 you're right, its the small things that we overlook sometimes. no worries